# Optionally replacing a substring python

Tags: python, string, replace

My list of replacement is in the following format.

```
lstrep = [('A',('aa','aA','Aa','AA')),('I',('ii','iI','Ii','II')),.....]
```

What I want to achieve is optionally change the occurrence of the letter by all the possible replacements. The input word should also be a member of the list.
e.g.

input - `DArA`

Expected output -

```
['DArA','DaarA','Daaraa','DAraa','DaArA','DAraA','DaAraA','DAarA','DAarAa', 'DArAa','DAArA','DAArAA','DArAA']
```

My try was

```
lstrep = [('A',('aa','aA','Aa','AA'))]
def alte(word,lstrep):
    output = [word]
    for (a,b) in lstrep:
        for bb in b:
            output.append(word.replace(a,bb))
    return output
print alte('DArA',lstrep)
```

The output I received was `['DArA', 'Daaraa', 'DaAraA', 'DAarAa', 'DAArAA']` i.e. All occurrences of 'A' were replaced by 'aa','aA','Aa' and 'AA' respectively. What I want is that it should give all permutations of optional replacements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`itertools.product` will give all of the permutations. You can build up a list of substitutions and then let it handle the permutations.

```
import itertools

lstrep = [('A',('aa','aA','Aa','AA')),('I',('ii','iI','Ii','II'))]
input_str = 'DArA'

# make substitution list a dict for easy lookup
lstrep_map = dict(lstrep)

# a substitution is an index plus a string to substitute. build
# list of subs [[(index1, sub1), (index1, sub2)], ...] for all
# characters in lstrep_map.
subs = []
for i, c in enumerate(input_str):
    if c in lstrep_map:
        subs.append([(i, sub) for sub in lstrep_map[c]])

# build output by applying each sub recorded
out = [input_str]
for sub in itertools.product(*subs):
    # make input a list for easy substitution
    input_list = list(input_str)
    for i, cc in sub:
        input_list[i] = cc
    out.append(''.join(input_list))

print(out)
```

Comment: Lovely. It made my day. Absolutely native and fast.

Answer (score 0):

Try constructing tuples of all possible permutations based on the replaceable characters that occur. **This will have to be achieved using recursion**.

The reason recursion is necessary is that you would need a variable number of loops to achieve this.

#### For your example "DArA" (2 replaceable characters, "A" and "A"):

```
replaceSet = set()
replacements = ['A':('aa','aA','Aa','AA'),'I':('ii','iI','Ii','II'),.....]
for replacement1 in replacements["A"]:
    for replacement2 in replacements["A"]:
        replaceSet.add((replacement1, replacement2))
```

You see you need two loops for two replaceables, and **`n` loops for `n` replaceables**.

---

Think of a way you could use recursion to solve this problem. It will likely involve creating all permutations for a substring that contains `n-1` replaceables (if you had `n` in your original string).